# Multiple layouts for different components in angular 2+

Tags: angular, components

I want to integrate multiple layouts for different components so I created 2 different layouts.
**i.e.** `inside.html`, `inside.ts` and `outside.html`, `outside.ts`.
Both components have different selectors so which one should I use in `index.html` file ? What is the exact way to achieve this ?

```
<div *ngIf="true">
<div id="wrapper">
  <navbar></navbar>
  <div class="gray-bg">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <footer></footer>
  </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="false">
<div class="blue">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Comment: when do you decide to use inside or outside, you may wrap both components in one and use `*ngIf` based upon your condition.

Comment: @MadhuRanjan, I tried `*ngIf` but it is showing error `cannot find primary outlet to load Component`.

Comment: have you wrapped both inside\outside in a component and using it?

Comment: I used 2 `*ngIf` based on condition.

Comment: can you add your code?

Comment: @MadhuRanjan, Check updated post.

Comment: they are not two components, you need to wrap into component.

Answer (score 0):

Build an AppComponent with a selector. Add its selector to index.html. Then add the code shown in your question to AppComponent.

This makes the bootstrapping process easier because there is only one component (AppComponent) that needs to be bootstrapped and used in index.html.

Comment: If I use `*ngIf` then it is giving error `cannot find primary outlet to load Component`.

Comment: Can you create a plunker that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: I solved issue by creating different layouts and without using `*ngIf`. I will add my answer soon.